# How do I implicitly differentiate $\frac{d}{dx}(2x(y')^2y'')$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I know that I will probably need to use the 3-way chain rule:
$$(fgh)'=f'gh+fg'h+fgh',$$ but since I'm differentiating in terms of $x$, I'm very confused as to how to to "append" $y'$ terms to the end of each term in the product rule expansion. For instance, I believe $\frac{d}{dx}(xy)=y+xy'(y')$, where I have "appended" a $y'$ to the latter term. This makes sense from the (informal) "fraction analogy" in Leibniz notation: $$\frac{d}{dx}=\frac{d}{dy}\cdot\frac{dy}{dx},$$ but I have trouble generalising to more complicated examples like the one mentioned above.

It would be much appreciated if someone can write out the full solution or explain how they got it.

**Note: $y=y(x)$** (is this noteworthy?)

Comment: For example $\frac{d}{dx}(2x(y')^2)=2(y')^2+4xy'y''$. I let you adapt this to your question.

Comment: I reckon you get $\frac{d}{dx}(2x(y’)^2y’’)=2(y’)^2y’’+4xy’(y’’)^2+2x(y’)^2y’’’$

Comment: What you call the "3-way chain rule" is really the 3-way product rule. And there is no real reason to have a separate 3-way product rule, the same way there is no reason to have a separate 3-way multiplication table in elementary school. You just use the regular 2-way rule twice.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$
((y')^2)' = \frac{\mathrm{d}(y')^2}{\mathrm{d}x} 
         = \frac{\mathrm{d}(y')^2}{\mathrm{d}y'} \frac{\mathrm{d}y'}{\mathrm{d}x}
         = 2y'y'',
$$
your 3-way chain rule leads to
$$
\begin{align}
(2x(y')^2y'')' &= (2x)'(y')^2y'' + 2x((y')^2)'y'' + 2x(y')^2(y'')' \\
               &= 2(y')^2y''     + 4xy'(y'')^2    + 2x(y')^2y'''.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Shouldn’t the middle term be $4$? An extra times $2$ from the square

Comment: @JackpotWizard180 Oh right, it's a little error. Thank you for the check, I'll correct it immediately.

Comment: @Arthur  Not my day, I guess...

Answer (score 0):

Use logarithmic differentiation
$$f(x)=2x(y')^2y''$$
$$\log(f(x))=\log(2)+\log(x)+2\log(y')+\log(y'')$$
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} =\frac d {dx} \log(f(x))=\frac 1x +2\frac{y''}{y'}+\frac{y'''}{y''}$$
$$f'(x)=\left( \frac 1x +2\frac{y''}{y'}+\frac{y'''}{y''}\right) f(x)$$

Simplify.